# How to create callback in custom function using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a custom callback function for a custom function and pass callback as a parameter.

```
function customFunction(a, b, callback) {
  // Some code
}

customFunction("val1", "val2", function(){
  //Code to execute after callback
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're almost there...

```
function customFunction(a, b, callback) {
    // Some code
    if (typeof callback === 'function') { 
        callback(); 
    }
}

customFunction("val1", "val2", function(){
  //Code to execute after callback
});
```

Comment: I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function"

Comment: I'd add `if (typeof callback === 'function') { callback(); }` in case you have no 3rd parameter.

Comment: Thanks, "if (typeof callback === 'function') { callback(); }" solved the issue :)

Comment: I've added that in to the solution

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Coulson is good. To show it more clearly we can add the timeout function as follow:

```
function customFunction(a, b, callback) {
     setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("original function");
      callback();
     },1000);


}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        customFunction("val1", "val2",function(){
            console.log("callback function");
       });
    });
});
```

Following is the link for check - https://jsfiddle.net/y0ch9exw/